# Show Price Above Add To Cart Button for configurable products using rwd theme

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, rwd-theme

My default / default theme in Magento 1.9 shows the product price in two places on the product page for configurable products; once near the top and again above the Add to Cart Button. But when I change the theme to rwd / default the price is no longer displayed near the Add To Cart Button.

Looking at template path hints I can see `price_clone.phtml` which includes `price.phtml` in the correct place above the Add To Cart Button on the page but the price still does not actually show when using the rwd them.

How do I get `price_clone.phtml` to work in the rwd theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RWD theme if you check the class in css

```
.product-options-bottom .price-box
```

in file `skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css` you will find the `display:none`

You will need to remove that line from css.